# Установить фон на canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Имеется изображение фона 50 на 50 px и холст размером 500 на 500, нужно изображениями фона заполнить весь холст. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
<canvas id='canvas' width=250 height=250></canvas>
<img src='http://900igr.net/up/datai/165870/0003-002-.png' id='img'/>
```

JS:

```
function ge(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
} 

const canvas = ge('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const canvasWidth = canvas.width;
const canvasHeight = canvas.height;
const img = ge('img');

for (let i = 0; i < canvasWidth; i += 50) {
  for (let j = 0; j < canvasHeight; j += 50) {
    ctx.drawImage(img, i, j);
  }
}
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pf8kdx10/12/)